# Can you view Angular's Guard/Service code using developer tools?

Tags: angular, developer-tools

When switching to `Sources` tab you can pretty much find all Angular's written code in the `webpack://` >> `.` folder, except for `Guards` - `Services` - `Component Styling File`.

Is there anyway I can find them somewhere else?

Comment: In my development environment, I am able to see all the source code in chrome developer tools, including all services and guards.  Put a `debugger` in the guard or service and you should hit a breakpoint at that code when loading it in a browser with dev tools open.  I would be very cautious about storing sensitive information within UI code.

Comment: @JeffryHouser - Thanks, i know i can use a `debugger` in my code, but say i didn't, can i find related code in the `developer tools`? that was my question.

Answer (score 0):

When you will build your Angular app in production mode (`ng build --configuration production`), Angular CLI will obfuscate your code so either way is good regarding code inspection.

Be careful with data in network requests, localStorage, cookies etc...

Comment: I'm strongly against the suggestion that "Angular Obfuscates code in production builds, so it is okay to store secure information in the code"

Comment: @JeffryHouser - Thanks for your concern! This actually made me double check the bundled code after building my code, and i noticed that such information can be obtained easily.